# Convert from zip utf8 to zip buffer javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, zip

I am working on a task where im using an API that gives me data from a zip file as:
`fs.readFile("test.zip", "utf8")`

But i want the data as an buffer henche: `fs.readFile("test.zip")`
I have tried something like:

```
  const utf8ToBuffer = (str) => {
    const buf = Buffer.alloc(str.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      buf[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
  };
```

But this is does not give me the same variable.

Simpler terms: i get a variable that is `fs.readFile("test.zip", "utf8")` , but i need to convert it to `fs.readFile("test.zip")`.

Answer (score 0):

> If no encoding is specified (using options.encoding), the data is returned as a  object.

You don't need to convert to utf8 and then to a buffer. You can read the file straight as a buffer by not specifying the encoding.

```
fs.readFile("test.zip"); //will return a buffer
```

Comment: The problem is that the API call gives me fs.readFile("test.zip", "utf8"), so i cannot change it

Comment: Could you give more details?

Comment: onst conf = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/zip",
  },
  auth: {
    username: "username",
    password: "password",
  },
};
try {
  const res = await axios.get("url", conf);

Comment: This is the API im req, res.data is fs.readFile("test.zip", "utf8")